# Where can I find a free/cheap small airplane wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, general-aviation, wing, equipment, experimental-aircraft

I am looking for a small airplane wing (e.g. Cessna 172, but not necessarily) to run some experiments prior to seeking an STC for a modification I am working on. Do you know where I can find a free abandoned wing, or a very cheap one? It doesn't have to be airworthy or functional at all, as I will just use it for standalone tests on the ground.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the U.S., and in Massachusetts if that's of any help

Comment: Google 'used airplane parts' - [Wentworth](http://www.wentworthaircraft.com/) comes to mind.  Be very clear you want something that is NOT airworthy - it will bring the price down a lot.  If you can get to [Airventure](http://www.eaa.org/en/airventure), check out the [FlyMarket](http://spirit.eaa.org/appscode/expocad/2016/flymarket.html)

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll be sure to check that out. I recently joined EAA and was already considering going to Airventure, so that's one more reason to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wings may be tough to come by as they generally last the life of the plane and can be re-skinned/fixed if need be so they are not scrapped all that frequently. You can try a used parts dealer like [this one](http://www.wentworthaircraft.com/) or [this one](http://hangarswap.com/) but they generally deal in air worthy parts which will not be cheap. Here is a guy [parting out a 152 in FL](http://www.barnstormers.com/classified_1142725_Parting+Out+Cessna+152.html) he "has wings", you may want to give him a call and check other part out [barnstormers](http://www.barnstormers.com/) adds.

Your best bet may be to wonder on down to your local GA field and ask some questions at the FBO or maintenance facility if there is one. Its more than likely someone has a wing or wing section that is no longer air worthy from some accident or the like. You may even just see a junked wing sitting in a field behind a hangar...

STC's are specific to part or aircraft/engine so testing on a generic wing may not be a good basis (depending on what  you are doing) you may want to get the wing from the aircraft you intend to STC.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is incredibly helpful! I'm having a look into all of that now. For the STC part of your answer, I 100% agree with you - the wing experiments I am going to run are to check and improve functionality of my system, but not to prepare for approval as I will have to work on the specific aircraft I am designing it for to get certified. I am just trying to reduce the time for which the aircraft is going to be grounded as much as I can.

Comment: @Aerocurious To add on a little to the answer specifically for you, you might want to check out Nashua-Boire Airport in NH because I have seen a section of really old planes that have been sitting there for years.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give them a call tomorrow. Thanks!